# Which are the "about eight packages supplied with the R distribution"?

Tags: r

From https://www.r-project.org/about.html

> R can be extended (easily) via packages. There are about eight packages supplied with the R distribution and many more are available through the CRAN family of Internet sites covering a very wide range of modern statistics.

Which are those "about eight packages"?

I know almost nothing about R but it seems interesting. This particular paragraph intrigues me. Finding out which are those eight packages can help a newbie understand what are the most important parts at the core of the R environment.

A couple of fast google searches provided little information.

Comment: `sessonInfo()` will tell you what packages are loaded into your R session. Ruinning `sessionInfo()` on a fresh R session will tell you what packages are loaded by default. For me: `stats`, `graphics`, `grDevices`, `utils`, `datasets`, `methods` and `base`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like there might be a few more now. You can check with

```
subset(as.data.frame(installed.packages()), Priority %in% c("base","recommended"), select=c(Package, Priority))
```

With R 3.4.1 I see

```
              Package    Priority
base             base        base
boot             boot recommended
class           class recommended
cluster       cluster recommended
codetools   codetools recommended
compiler     compiler        base
datasets     datasets        base
foreign       foreign recommended
graphics     graphics        base
grDevices   grDevices        base
grid             grid        base
KernSmooth KernSmooth recommended
lattice       lattice recommended
MASS             MASS recommended
Matrix         Matrix recommended
methods       methods        base
mgcv             mgcv recommended
nlme             nlme recommended
nnet             nnet recommended
parallel     parallel        base
rpart           rpart recommended
spatial       spatial recommended
splines       splines        base
stats           stats        base
stats4         stats4        base
survival     survival recommended
tcltk           tcltk        base
tools           tools        base
utils           utils        base
```

But many of these are included for historical reasons. They may not be the best examples of "modern" R packages.

Answer (score 0):

Following on MrFlick's answer.

Found at this presentation: http://faculty.washington.edu/kenrice/rintro/sess08.pdf

Below are some of the CRAN packages that Come with base R:

#### KernSmooth

Functions for kernel smoothing (and density estimation) corresponding to the book "Kernel Smoothing" by M. P. Wand and M. C. Jones, 1995.

#### MASS

Functions and datasets from the main package of Venables and Ripley, "Modern Applied Statistics with S". (Contained in the vR bundle for Riversions prior to 2.10.0.)

#### Matrix

A Matrix package. (Recommended for R2.90 or later.)

#### boot

Functions and datasets for bootstrapping from the book "Bootstrap Methods and Their Applications" by A. C. Davison and D.W. Hinkley, 1997, Cambridge University Press.

#### class

Functions for classification (k-nearest neighbor and LVQ). (Contained in the vR bundle for Riversions prior to 2.10.0.)

#### cluster

Functions for cluster analysis.

#### codetools

Code analysis tools. (Recommended for R2.5.0 or later.)

#### foreign

Functions for reading and writing data stored by statistical software like Minitab, S, SAS, SPSS, Stata, Systat, etc.

#### lattice

Lattice graphics, an implementation of Trellis Graphics functions.

#### mgcv

Routines for GAMs and other generalized ridge regression problems with multiple smoothing parameter selection by GCV or UBRE.

#### mlme

Fit and compare Gaussian linear and nonlinear mixed-effects models.

#### nnet

Software for single hidden layer perceptrons ("feed-forward neural networks"), and for multinomial log-linear models. (Contained in the VR bundle for R versions prior to 2.10.0.)

#### rpart

Recursive PARTitioning and regression trees.

#### spatial

Functions for kriging and point pattern analysis from "Modern Applied Statistics with S" by W. Venables and B. Ripley. (Contained in the wrbundle for R versions prior to 2.10.0.)

#### survival

Functions for survival analysis, including penalized likelihood.